# How can I change the layer from USR to ISV in Dynamics 365 for Operation?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

By default I'm working on the USR, since working on this layer is not best practice, I need to work on the ISV layer in Dynamics 365. How could I change the layer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a project is created with the help of Dynamics365 menu on top of visual studio you cannot change the USR layer to ISV layer.

You can click on Dynamics 365 menu select model management and then click Create Model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to modify the `XML` in the `Descriptor` directory and change the `<Layer>14</Layer>` to `<Layer>8</Layer>` where `8 = ISV`.